# Complex PHP Form Data

Tags: php, forms

I have a form with a multi-level tree of one to many relationships. For example:

```
Match -> Phase 1 -> Phase Property 1
      -> Phase 1 -> Phase Property 2

      -> Phase 2 -> Phase Property 1
      -> Phase 2 -> Phase Property 2
      -> Phase 2 -> Phase Property 3

      -> Phase 3 -> Phase Property 1
      -> Phase 3 -> Phase Property 2
```

So, on the front-end I am able to add many phases to a match and many phase properties to a phase.

In the PHP back-end, I would like to be able to represent this data in a multi-dimensional array, so that I can loop through all the phases and then loop through each phase's properties. Ideally, I would like to stay away from managing Ids/names through JavaScript.

I know I can receive an array in PHP using something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="phases[]" />
```

But, how do I continue this pattern for the properties? Can I do something like:

```
<input type="text" name="phaseProperties[][]" />
```

and then somehow "link" each property to the right phase?

Comment: phaseProperties[phase1][] - create 'phase1' dynamically with JS as you add things to the list.

Comment: So, it must require managing phase Ids with JS? I was hoping I could keep the phase properties linked to the phase based on index (0, 1, 2 ...)

Comment: it will work the same, if 0 => phase1 you could phaseProperties[0][]. You will somehow need to tell php which phase a particular property belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input fields appear on a static page, then you should already know how much input fields you are going to make on the server side. So why is using fields like:

```
<input type="text" name="phaseProperties[0][]" />
<input type="text" name="phaseProperties[0][]" />
<input type="text" name="phaseProperties[1][]" />
```

such a bad thing? If the fields are being dynamically (client-side) generated then there shouldn't be a problem naming them dynamically aswell. You seem to be constraining yourself too much for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do like:

```
<input type="text" name="phaseProperties[Phase1][Property1]" />
<input type="text" name="phaseProperties[Phase1][Property2]" />
<input type="text" name="phaseProperties[Phase1][Property3]" />
<input type="text" name="phaseProperties[Phase2][Property1]" />
<input type="text" name="phaseProperties[Phase2][Property2]" />
<input type="text" name="phaseProperties[Phase2][Property3]" />
```

And in backend PHP, you will get phaseProperties like this:

```
Array
(
[Phase1] => Array
(
[Property1] => a
[Property2] => b
[Property3] => c
)

[Phase1] => Array
(
[Property1] => d
[Property2] => e
[Property3] => f
)

)
```

Comment: I understand what your saying. But, I was hoping to stay away from managing things with JavaScript. For example, link the properties to the phase by index (0, 1, 2 ...)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use (actually you can, but it doesn't help you)

```
<input type="text" name="phaseProperties[][]" />
```

because PHP has no way of knowing how you want your items grouped. It will add each item into a separate group.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Item 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Item 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Item 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Item 4
        )
)
```

There isn't anything special about using `[]` in parameters. They behave exactly as the `[]` operator in PHP. For example:

```
$arr[][] = 'Item 1';
$arr[][] = 'Item 2';
$arr[][] = 'Item 3';
$arr[][] = 'Item 4';
print_r($arr);
```

would have the same output I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

When you render the UI (HTML), you could just use php to loop over and outputs the input?

```
$phases = 3;
$phasesProperty = array(
    array(1, 2),
    array(1, 2, 3),
    array(1, 2)
);

for($i = 0; $i < $phases; $i++) {
    foreach($phasesProperty[$i] as $j) {
        printf('<input type="text" name="Match[Phase%d][PhaseProperty%d]" />', $i, $j);
    }
}
```